# MongoDB distinct query

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

I have a collection of products, in which some of the products have the same URL and I can't avoid having those duplicates (The db is populated by a third party).

I'm trying to come up with an efficient query to fetch only distinct products (without getting two products with the same url).

This is what I've come up with so far:

```
db.product.find({_id: {$in: 
  db.product.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            searchName: /iphone 8.*/i,
            isAvailable: true
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$url",
            id: {$max: "$_id"}
        }
    }
  ]).map(a => a.id)
}}).limit(10);
```

The inner `aggregate` will return the IDs of the distinct products, and the outer `find` will fetch them.

It works fine, but it takes more than twice the time that a regular query.
Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making 2 queries - first one to get `id`s and the second one to fetch documents by `id`s. You can perfectly combine both in a single pipeline:

```
db.product.aggregate([
{ $sort: {_id: -1} },
{
    $match: {
        searchName: /iphone 8.*/i,
        isAvailable: true
    }
},
{
    $group: {
        _id: "$url",
        docs: {$push: "$$ROOT"}
    }
},
{ $replaceRoot: { newRoot: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$docs", 0 ] } } }
])
```

[$replaceRoot](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/) is available since v3.4. A workaround for this stage to be used in older versions could be

```
{ $project: {_id: 0, product: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$docs", 0 ] } } }
```

Comment: This command throws this error: Error: command failed: {
 "ok" : 0,
 "errmsg" : "Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$replaceRoot'",
 "code" : 16436
} : aggregate failed

Comment: @AlexandreJustino, I have added a workaround for ancient versions of the db, but I'd strongly recommend to upgrade. v3.0 is already dead, and v3.2 reaches end of life in half-year time.